# How to add a column to a Pandas dataframe made of arrays of the n-preceding values of another column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and pandas. I don't know how to solve the following problem *in an elegant way*.

Let's say we have a simple pandas dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,60,10), columns=['Value'])
```

[image: A very simple pandas dataframe]

Now set a variable, e.g.:

```
n = 3
```

The goal is to **add a column** to df, **made of arrays of the n-preceding values**, as following:

[image: pandas dataframe with a columns made of arrays]

The next step could be to set NaNs to zero.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Gilbert

Comment: Can you already generate the `ArrayValues` column?

Comment: No. The goal is a simple command/function to generate the column, in a vectorized way if possible.

Comment: Next time, add code instead of pictures of your pandas dataframe ;)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Afke I don't think code would have helped here, the image really makes the question really clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `df.shift` to generate the offset columns and a list comprehension to group them together then `map` to generate a `list` of `lists` for the `dataframe`. However, the `list` of `lists` generated will need to be transposed first before assigning it to the original `df` so that we have an list of values corresponding to the correct row.

```
df["b"] =np.array(map(list,[df["a"].shift(x) for x in range(1,4)])).T.tolist()
```

Input:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Output:

```
   a                b
0  1  [nan, nan, nan]
1  2  [1.0, nan, nan]
2  3  [2.0, 1.0, nan]
3  4  [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Thank you @Yarnspinner, I tried you code but I get: `<map object at 0x111bafda0>` values for the column `b`. Your code is inspiring me.

Comment: I changed your code to `df["b"] = np.array(list(map(list,[df["a"].shift(x) for x in range(1,4)]))).T.tolist()` adding `np.array(list(map`. Now it works perfectly. Thank you @Yarnspinner.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little gnarly to wrangle but the following works:

```
In [63]:
def func(x):
    return pd.Series(df['Value'], index=np.arange(x.name-3,x.name)).values.tolist()
df['ArrayValues'] = df[['Value']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df
​
Out[63]:
   Value       ArrayValues
0      0   [nan, nan, nan]
1     10   [nan, nan, 0.0]
2     20  [nan, 0.0, 10.0]
3     30       [0, 10, 20]
4     40      [10, 20, 30]
5     50      [20, 30, 40]
```

So firstly we double subscript the df using `[[]]` so that we force the single column into a df so we can call `apply` and use param `axis=1` to `apply` our `func` row-wise, this is required because we want to use the current row index value accessed via `name` attribute to return a re-indexed `Series` based on the index range, as the index values don't exist it creates `NaN` values for the index rows that don't exist, finally we need to anonymize the data by returning a numpy array and convert this to a list so we don't try to align on the Series index

**edit**

if we swap the start/stop args to `np.arange` with a negative step then you get the order you desire:

```
In [70]:
def func(x):
    return pd.Series(df['Value'], index=np.arange(x.name-1,x.name-4,-1)).values.tolist()
df['ArrayValues'] = df[['Value']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df
​
Out[70]:
   Value       ArrayValues
0      0   [nan, nan, nan]
1     10   [0.0, nan, nan]
2     20  [10.0, 0.0, nan]
3     30       [20, 10, 0]
4     40      [30, 20, 10]
5     50      [40, 30, 20]
```

Comment: Thank you @EdChum I tried you code and I get the same result. Now I have to make a small change to get the arrays ordered as requested: e.g `[40, 30, 20]` instead of `[20, 30, 40]`.

Comment: So you want it sorted on values or you're just interest in reverse order?

Comment: e.g. the 5th row must contain an array made of 4, 3, 2 row values in this order.