# How to get the minimum value of a row list in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, row, min

I have a pandas dataframe with a column made of *lists*.
The goal is to find the min of every list in row (in an efficient way).

E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Lists', 'Min'])
df['Lists'] = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
print(df)
```

The goal is the `Min` column:

```
       Lists  Min
0  [1, 2, 3]  1
1  [4, 5, 6]  4
2  [7, 8, 9]  7
```

Thank you in advance,
gil

Comment: Since your `pandas` data structures are using the `object` dtype, you are killing efficiency.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is the output of this algo `df["b"] =np.array(map(list,[df["a"].shift(x) for x in range(1,4)])).T.tolist()` - see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967824/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-pandas-dataframe-made-of-arrays-of-the-n-preceding-valu].

Is there a way to speed up?

Comment: The issue is that you are putting lists inside your `DataFrame`, making it of dtype `object`. The dtype is inherited for the underlying numpy data structure, and `object` dtypes are slow. It's not the algorithm, it's your data structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `min`:

```
df['Min'] = df.Lists.apply(lambda x: min(x))
print (df)
       Lists  Min
0  [1, 2, 3]    1
1  [4, 5, 6]    4
2  [7, 8, 9]    7
```

Thank you [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064624/how-to-get-the-minimum-value-of-a-row-list-in-a-pandas-dataframe/42064642#comment71300823_42064642) for idea:

```
df['Min'] = [min(x) for x in df.Lists.tolist()]
print (df)
       Lists  Min
0  [1, 2, 3]    1
1  [4, 5, 6]    4
2  [7, 8, 9]    7
```

**Timings**:

```
##[300000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [144]: %timeit df['Min1'] = [min(x) for x in df.Lists.values.tolist()]
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop

In [145]: %timeit df['Min2'] = [min(x) for x in df.Lists.tolist()]
10 loops, best of 3: 142 ms per loop

In [146]: %timeit df['Min3'] = [min(x) for x in df.Lists]
10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop

In [147]: %timeit df['Min4'] = df.Lists.apply(lambda x: min(x))
10 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop
```

Comment: Heck, a list-comprehension on the `Lists` column might be faster.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael (amazing speed of answer)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Thank you very much, you are right - I add timings to solution.